# Python: how do I split() each symbol until reach separator symbol

Tags: python, split

I have a string:

```
a = "12356789:10:51:52:53"
```

As a result, I need a list like:

```
['1','2','3','5','6','7','8','9','10','51','52','53']
```

How can I split one by one symbols until I find `:` separator?

Comment: `first = re.search(':', a).span()[0]` then `re.split('', a[:first])[1:-1] + a[first:].split(':')` or `list(a[:first]) + a[first:].split(':')`. Assumes all individual values precede values separated by `:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
list((x:="12356789:10:51:52:53".split(":"))[0]) + x[1:]
```

Comment: How does the ```:=``` operator work? For me it's somehow showing invalid syntax.

Comment: @porrrwal It was introduced in [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

A short tricky way for fun (wouldn't recommend for production code :-):

```
a = "12356789:10:51:52:53"

[*b], *b[len(a):] = a.split(':')

print(b)
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '51', '52', '53']
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution but this would work:

```
a = "12356789:10:51:52:53"
list(''.join(a.split(":")[0])) + a.split(":")[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this do?

```
a = "12356789:10:51:52:53"

l1 = a.split(":")
l2 = [c for c in l1[0]]
output = l2 + l1[1:]
output
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [193]: a = "12356789:10:51:52:53"

In [194]: first_split = a.index(':')

In [195]: a[:first_split].split()
Out[195]: ['12356789']

In [196]: a = "12356789:10:51:52:53"

In [197]: b = list(a[:first_split])
Out[197]: ['1', '2', '3', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

In [198]: c = a[first_split+1:].split(':')
Out[198]: ['10', '51', '52', '53']
```

Then you can combine `b+c`